# Django Python, ftp memory leak

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks, ftp, out-of-memory

I'm working on a project that make possible the comunication between web app and a list of devices. Every device upload via ftp a cvv file with only one row o data than my application load that data into db and mark the comunication between the divice and my app.
Every time a device uploads a file the server ram memory is increasing till it crashes.

**http:// i.stack.imgur.com/yHeuu.png**

I have added memory_profiler to my ftp handler, here is a piece of code:

**http:// i.stack.imgur.com/BQur5.png**

Everytime I upload a file Mem Usage is increasing by 0.1MiB and it won't drop till the server kills the process.

I've added a gardbage collector at the end of the function but it works only for 30 transfers after that it starts increasing again.

Comment: Have you set `debug=False` in the settings file? When in debug mode Django saves all database queries, leading to a "memory leak"

Comment: You can also use `django.db.reset_queries()` to reset the list of saved queries.

Comment: I've found one debug= True and I've set it to False, now It handles about 50 transfers the it start increasing again. If I'm using db.reset_queris() it increases memory on each transfer